# Returning [Object object] from json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm having trouble returning a status message from a php file to an ajax function in an html file. When go to submit I get [Object object] on the screen. From what I understand json_encode would be able to return the object $answer with its value. Am I missing something here?

php

```
<?php  
 require_once 'dbconfig.php';
 require_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php');
 ob_start();

  $answer = new stdClass;
 if(isset($_POST))
 {
     $uname;
     $pword;
     //email = ema
     $ema;

     $answer->result = "successful";
     $answer->text = "";
     foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
     {
        if($key == 'u')
        {
            $uname = $value;
        }
        else if($key == 'p')
        {
            $pword = $value;
        } 
        else if($key == 'em')
        {
            $ema = $value;
        }
     }
    }
    else
    {
        $answer->result = "Error";
        $answer->text = "Error Message";
    }

    $check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'")  or die(mysql_error());  
    $check2 = mysqli_num_rows($check);

    if ($check2 != 0) {  
    $answer->text = "sorry username taken";
    $ansr = json_encode($answer);
    echo $ansr;
    die('Sorry, the username is already in use.'); 
     }
   exit(0);
?>
```

ajax in my html file

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registration.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data : { u: un, p:p1, e:em },
            cache: !1,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#submit").hide();
                $('#status').text('please wait ...');
            },
            complete: function(){
                $("#submit").show();
            },
            success: function(answer){
                if(answer.result == "successful")
                {
                    $("#status").html(answer.text);
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#status").html(answer.result);
                }
            },
            error: function(answer){
                $("#status").text(answer);
            }
        });
```

any advice or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your JSON is actually OK, but the ajax call ends up int the `error` branch, which just prints out the whole `answer` object. If you'd use `$("#status").html(answer.text);` instead of `$("#status").text(answer);` you should see the correct error message.

Comment: inspect the object in console. You need to do some basic debugging using the dev tools built into your browser

Comment: echo $ansr followed by die(str) will corrupt your json output

Comment: if you use `die(msg)` after sending the json data it will invalidate the json data

Comment: @RamRaider you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RamRaider ! 
Using die() right after using json_encode invalidated the data.